# What is the root directory used by SonarQube parameter sonar.exclusions?

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I am using SonarQube to analyse my .Net projects for years.

But I still do not catch what is the root directory used by the parameter `sonar.exclusions`.

So I use **/ to prefix every file path...

Could anybody enlighten me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Iin the context of inclusions/exclusions the path is going to start from what you fed in as `sonar.sources`. If you have doubts, you can look at the path the SonarQube interface gives you to any particular file.

Comment: But I can't use the sonar.sources parameter because of this bug : https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-msbuild/issues/456. So, if sonar.sources is not completed, what is the root directory? Typically, I have a .Net solution and I want to exclude one project. (I used jenkins and scanner for msbuild)